# Flutter Page refresh problem | ListView showing a error "BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 98 PIXEL"

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working a messaging app based on firebase. I am a having problem in the home page. I created the home page to show the last message, the user name, and the profile pic of the user who send the message. But  when I am getting back from the chatscreen only the last message is updating. And the last message did not showing the correct user who send the message. But after hot reload it is showing correctly .
And the ListView builder did not scrolling. It is showing a error "BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 98 PIXEL".
How can I fixed those problems?

```
  Widget chatRoomsList() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: chatRoomsStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
              return ChatRoomListTile(ds.id, ds["lastMessage"], myUserName);
            })
        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
}
```

ChatRoomList Tile:

```
class _ChatRoomListTileState extends State<ChatRoomListTile> {
  String profilePicUrl = "", name = "", username = "";

  getThisUserInfo() async {
    username =
        widget.chatRoomId.replaceAll(widget.myUserName, "").replaceAll("_", "");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await DatabaseMethods().getUserInfo(username);
    print("something the data we are getting ${querySnapshot.docs[0].id}");
    name = "${querySnapshot.docs[0]["name"]}";
    profilePicUrl = querySnapshot.docs[0]["imgUrl"];
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getThisUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        before going to charRoom
         Navigator.push(
             context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (context) => ChatScreen(
                 username,
                 name,
               ),
            ));
      },

      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child: Image.network(
              profilePicUrl,
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 12),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
              SizedBox(height: 3),

              Container(
                width: 200,
                child: Text(
                  widget.lastMessage,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: HexColor("#E6F4F7"),
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                  softWrap: false,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Full home page code: https://github.com/Monzim/messengerClone/blob/main/lib/views/home.dart

[image]

Comment: You get error in `ChatRoomListTile` class?

Comment: Yes. In the ChatRoomListTile class.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the floating part on the screen.

Comment: Yes. I have added it. For seeing this error I changed the "SizedBox(height: 30)," value to 300

Comment: It looks your code is right of `ChatRoomListTile`. The error is on different screen

Comment: But I am having this problem in the home screen. And in the home screen I called `ChatRoomListTile` .

Comment: widget build (BuildContext context) Wrap the body of the scaffold with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: @hasankaraman but by wrapping whole body the textfield is also scroll and this is not right approch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated my answer you can put this code into your `Home class`

```
  Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
           ...// Your Child
        ],
      ),
      isSearching ? Expanded(child: searchUserList()) : Expanded(child: chatRoomsList(),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: @AzrafAlMonzim please recheck my answer

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. Can you please help me for solve the other problem?

Comment: @AzrafAlMonzim Kindly please do mark it as true for other developers to easily find answer.

Comment: @AzrafAlMonzim Yes I'll help you for other problems

Comment: Thank you so much. It will be very helpful for me 